# Entity MVC adding a new row and grabbing the id used

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity

I have a method that adds a new row for a table.  What I need to do is grab that ID it used for that row and put it into my sortOrder row as well.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddProcedure(Procedures procedure, FormCollection collection)
        {

            procedure.processID = Convert.ToInt32(collection["DropDownList.SelectedIndexId"]);
            // ADD Default KPI
            db.Procedure.Add(procedure);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("AddProcedure", "MasterList");
        }
```

How would I grab the `ID` and add it to `procedures.sortOrder`

Answer (score 1):

The `procedure` object should be getting updated with the auto-generated id from the database.

```
db.Procedure.Add(procedure);
db.SaveChanges();

var id = procedure.ID;
```